# Converting ResultSet to DTOs has unexpected result

Tags: java, hash, resultset

EDIT: forgot a line of code that is likely causing the issue (night's sleep helped ;)

Ok it's late so I'm probably missing something fundamental here but this is my issue:

I have query my db and get a data set that looks like this:

```
retail_store_id basket_item_id  price_txt
1           2       8.99
1           1       1.5
1           6       11.09
1           4       3.99
2           6       10.99
2           2       9
2           1       1.79
3           4       2.99
3           1       1.5
4           1       1.39
4           6       9.99
4           4       3.5
4           2       7.99
```

Now I have a Store class which contains a List items and each basketitem has a price.

now to get that into my dto's I do this:

```
    Map<Integer, Store> shoppedBasketHash = new HashMap<Integer, Store>();
    while (rs.next()){
            int storeID = rs.getInt("retail_store_id");

            basketItem = new BasketItem();
                            basketItem = GlobalHashOfItems.get(rs.getInt("basket_item_id"));
            basketItem.price = new BigDecimal(rs.getString("price_txt"));

            if(shoppedBasketHash.containsKey(storeID)){
                shoppedBasketHash.get(storeID).items.add(basketItem);                   
            }else{

                Store store = new Store();
                store.retailStoreID = rs.getInt("retail_store_id");

                store.items = new ArrayList<BasketItem>();
                store.items.add(basketItem);

                shoppedBasketHash.put(storeID, sb);
            }
        }
   return new ArrayList<Store>(shoppedBasketHash.values());
```

Now for some reason, later on when I take this list:

```
    for(Store s: listOfStores){
        for(BasketItem b: s.items){
                         System.out.println(b.price);
                    }
        }
```

I get this: 
9.99

3.5

7.99

1.39

1.39

9.99

7.99

1.39

3.5

3.5

7.99

1.39

9.99

Which is not the same list of prices I took in. What am I doing wrong?

I realize now the issue is in the 
    basketItem = GlobalHashOfItems.get(rs.getInt("basket_item_id"));

I have a hash of items (without prices) that contains other item info not pulled from the DB that I need to use then add the price too. But it's not copying by value it's using an object reference. How do I make basketItem get assigned to the value of the GlobalHashOfItems item and not a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `HashMap` does not preserve insertion/iteration order when it is converted into an `ArrayList` to return from your method.

You can solve this by building the `ArrayList` to return while using the `Map` for addition.

Another way would be to use a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which does preserve insertion/iteration order.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that my return statement might be an issue and I have never used the values() before.

However I tried this:

  `List<Store> stores = new ArrayList<Store>();
  Set<Integer> keys = shoppedBasketHash.keySet();
  for(Integer i: keys){
   stores.add(shoppedBasketHash.get(i));
  }
  
  return stores;`
  

I'm still getting the same results

Comment: @PiersMacDonald, your try suffers from the same problem; iteration over (unsorted) `Map` and `Set` is in random order. If your goal is to reproduce the sequence of the resulset, add to an `ArrayList` when you put the store in the map. If your goal is to sort the result on key value (like your try above) you can achive it by using an ordered map like `TreeMap`. (The same holds for the iteratino sequence of the `store.items()` of course.)